# "Access to the path 'Calculations.pdb' is denied." But access is fine for all the other files

Tags: c#

We have C# code that gets compiled dynamically and saved in a folder, let's say Assembly. The program is run as administrator.

When we rebuild the assembly, we delete all the files in the folder Assembly.
There is no problem when deleting the .cs and .dll files, but the .pdb file (as in the title) doesn't get deleted and the exception is thrown.

Why do I have this problem only with the pdb file?

Comment: Is the file open in another process or application?

Comment: Have you investigated what a .pdb file is?

Comment: @peeebeee, I don't think so. Wouldn't it also have trouble deleting the dll file then?

Comment: @AndyG, yes I have read up on it, though I'm sure my understanding isn't perfect. :-)

Comment: I can delete the pdb file manually, -no problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the pdb file's symbols were loaded in Visual Studio, and thus when I was debugging it couldn't be deleted. I was debugging to see what the error was.
So when I didn't load the symbols automatically anymore, it worked.